Network Manager does not see cdc_ether interface
I have Telit modem which provides a wwan0 interface.
It is an ECM (Ethernet Control Model) type of interface using the cdc_ether driver
I can set up the interface manually, and it works. But I am unable to use NetworkManager to manage it. It seems that NetworkManager does not even see the interface.
Note that I do not want to use ModemManager and ppp.
Any ideas on how to get NetworkManager to see the device?
I am using Raspberry Pi OS 64bit /Debian Bookworm.
root@pi64:~# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 4, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M

root@pi64:~# ip addr show wwan0
3: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:be:93:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.225.20/24 brd 192.168.225.255 scope global dynamic wwan0
       valid_lft 41430sec preferred_lft 41430sec
    inet6 fe80::2a0:c6ff:febe:9340/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@pi64:~# nmcli d
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION         
eth0           ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1 
lo             loopback  connected (externally)  lo                 
wlan0          wifi      disconnected            --                 
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --  

root@pi64:~# nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname wwan0 con-name ecm
Connection 'ecm' (1f312b0e-c41c-4717-b4e9-26704d522baf) successfully added.
root@pi64:~# sudo nmcli dev set wwan0 managed yes
Error: Device 'wwan0' not found.
root@pi64:~# nmcli con up ecm
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device eth0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).
root@pi64:~# 

root@pi64:~# ping -I wwan0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.225.20 wwan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=28 time=400 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=28 time=101 ms

Linux pi64 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.63-1+rpt1 (2023-11-24) aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@pi64:~# cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
root@pi64:~# 



